# Where to download Skype version 6?

Tags: windows, windows-8, skype

I have this problem - Skype 7 causes my machine to hang up every other time whenever I finish talking to someone. This did not happen with older versions and searching the Internet reveals that many folks have this problem with Skype 7 (any version) and that the only viable solution is to downgrade.

The only problem is that all the downgrade links are either dead or bogus. So, does anyone know of a reliable archive where I could download the full Skype 6 installer (not the web installer, of course)?

Comment: [This](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/skype/) is where to go: it's an amazingly useful site.

Comment: Im second on this - M$ blocked old versions

Comment: @AFH - I am unable to download, seems like the browser blocks downloads from this site.

Comment: Try a different browser, or your current browser in safe mode, after checking that the site is not black-listed in your firewall.

Comment: I see from oднокласспик on your profile picture that you are Russian-speaking. The site may have geographic limitations. I don't know where else to recommend. I still run Skype 6.16, because of recent changes to device support and, apart from frequent nags to update, it works fine.

Comment: @AFH - I am in Canada. The download on the site is too small - just over 1MB, so it is a web installer. Do not think it will work, but I try. Do you have the actual download for your version?

Comment: @AFH - tried again. No luck. Maybe my organization blocks sites that are deemed unsafe.

Comment: I have Skype 6.9 SetUp: I updated from that to 6.16, then stopped upgrading. It's a full installation 31MB file.

Comment: My Kaspersky Internet Security has no problems with the site.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked just fine - https://archive.org/details/SkypeSetup6

I now have Skype 6 - hooray!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you can try to reinstall your windows or upgrade to newer version of windows if your ram memory allows that. Then you will see a new wonderful set of programs and lists that go up with the new version. It will no bother you any more means for weakness of strength or further development of the scheme. I think installing a modem can also help or just install new windows

Comment: Reinstall Windows as a solution is rather extreme and defeats the purpose of other potential easier solutions but I guess a solution is a solution assuming you confirm the solution which if you reinstall and install on a fresh install of Windows, that's not really solving the problem at the level it began, right?